# How to write an Image to string in Julia?

Tags: string, image, encoding, julia

I want to encode an image in my directory "x.png" to a `String` or `Array{UInt8, 1}`.

I am writing a code in Julia to serialize an image using protobufs. It requires the image to be in encoded 
String format.

In Python, it is done as follows. I am looking for similar functionality in Julia.

```py
from PIL import Image
img = Image.load('x.png')
import io
output = io.BytesIO()
img.save(output, 'PNG')
img_string_data = output.getvalue()
output.close()
```

The output may be a `String` object or an `Array{UInt8, 1}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Julia you can achieve by writing:

```
img_string_data = read("x.png")
```

`img_string_data` now is `Vector{UInt8}`. You could also write `read("x.png", String)` to get a `String` (which is not that useful though as it will probably mostly contain invalid characters).

There is one difference between Julia solution and your Python solution. Julia approach will store in `img_string_data` the contents identical to what `"x.png"` holds on binary level while your Python solution will store an identical image, but possibly different on binary level (i.e. `PIL` might change some bytes in your file).